# Question regarding the proof that if a mapping has an inverse, it is also bijective.

Tags: functions

To show that an invertible mapping $f:A\mapsto B$ is bijective, we are required to show that it is both injective and surjective. I understand the portion of the proof that deals with injectivity just fine, but my question lies in the surjectivity portion. To prove that $f$ is surjective, we suppose that $b\in B$. Then we let $a=f^{-1}(b)$, where $f^{-1}$ denotes the inverse of $f$. We have therefore that $f^{-1}:B\mapsto A$, and thus $a\in A$. From here we have that $f(a)=f(f^{-1}(b))=\mathrm{id}_B(b)=b$.

My concern is with the line where we let $a=f^{-1}(b)$. Is it not true that this line assumes that $\forall b\in B$, $\exists a\in A$ such that $a=f^{-1}(b)$? That is, are we not assuming that $f^{-1}$ is surjective to prove that $f$ is surjective? The logic seems fairly circular to me.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are trying to prove that if it has an inverse then it is bijective, If it has an inverse, then there is some function denoted $f^{-1}$ and defined on $B$ such that $f (f^{-1}(y)) = y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your concern arises simply because the theorem is so obvious that it is hard to dissociate the bijectivity from the invertibility of the function. It is very intuitively clear that a function is bijective iff it is invertible.

Regardless, the proof is not circular. By definition, an invertible function $f:A\to B$ is one such that there exists another function $g:B\to A$ so that $g(f(x))=x$ for all $x\in A$ and $f(g(x))=x$ for all $x\in B$. If we assume that $f$ is invertible, then such a $g$ exists, and since $g$ is defined on the entire domain of $B$ this means that indeed each and every element of $B$ is mapped to something inside $A$. So it is not circular to let $a=g(b)$ (or $a=f^{-1}(b)$, if we switch notation). Of course, you correctly observe that we could not have done this if $f$ were not surjective, but in that case then $f$ would not be invertible, since no such $g:B\to A$ would exist.

Comment: Concise and clear. Thanks.